# Spark streaming slow down when using large broadcast objects in UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming, databricks

I do stream processing from Event Hub using Spark and faced the following problem. For each incoming message I need to do some calculations (stateless). The calculation algorithm is written using Scala and is extremely efficient but needs some data structures constructed in advance. The object size is about 50MB, but in future could be larger. In order not to send the object to the workers each time, I do broadcasting. Then register an UDF. But it doesn't help, batch duration is growing significantly beyond the latency we could dwell. I figured out that batch duration depends solely on the object size. For testing purpose I tried to make the object smaller keeping computation complexity the same, and the batch duration decreased. Also, when the object is large, Spark UI marks GC red (more than 10% of work is due to garbage collection). It contradicts my understanding of broadcasting that when an object is broadcasted, that object should be downloaded into the workers' memory and persisted there without additional overhead.

I managed to write business domain agnostic example. Here when n is small, batch duration is about 0.3 second, but when n = 6000 (144MB), the batch duration becomes 1.5 (x5), and 4 seconds when n=10000. But computation complexity doesn't depend on the size of the object. So, it means, that using broadcast object has huge overhead. Please, help me to find the solution.

```
// emulate large precalculated object
val n = 10000
val obj = (1 to n).map(i => (1 to n).toArray).toArray

// broadcast it to the workers (should reduce overhead during execution)
val objBd = sc.broadcast(obj)

// register UDF
val myUdf = spark.udf.register("myUdf", (num: Int) => {
  // emulate very efficient algorithm that requires large data structure
  var i = (num+1)/(num+1)
  objBd.value(i)(i)
})

// do stream processing
spark.readStream
  .format("rate")
  .option("rowsPerSecond", 300)
  .load()
  .withColumn("result", myUdf($"value"))
  .writeStream
  .format("memory")
  .queryName("locations")
  .start()
```

Comment: Try to increase the rows x sec. And check the stages in the console, to see if the driver is trying to shuffle the object each mini-batch

Comment: Were you able to determine that the overhead is *not* due to the broadcasting itself? (like one-off overhead)